# How to disconnect all peers with multipeerConnectivity?

Tags: ios, swift, connection, multipeer-connectivity

I have an app where a peer to peer network is created. There is a leader and members. If a member leaves, it just disconnects itself with `session.disconnect()`. But if the leader leaves, I want all the other members to get disconnected from each other as well.

[Disconnect individual peers from MCSession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435754/disconnect-individual-peers-from-mcsession)

I've seen this post for an Objective-C solution to disconnecting other peers, but didn't understand it. Can someone give me a good way to disconnect all peers of the `session.connectedPeers` at once?

Comment: I think you can manage this scenario by sending some specific text/code to all the user, before the leader leaves. Based on that text/code you can call session.disconnect() for every user.

Comment: @BhavikModi yes, but isn't there an easier solution?

Comment: Can you please just explain how do you making connection between users? For eg. Many users connecting to 1 or A connecting to B, B connecting to C.